# What is the file path location for QT Maintenance tool on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt

I have been searching and searching and cannot find where the QT Maintenance tool is located in Linux.

What is the default installation folder/file path for QT Maintenance tool for Ubuntu Linux distro.

Comment: Did you install the tool?

Answer (score 4):

If you left the defaults when using Qt's pre-built package installer, it should be in `~/Qt/`.

If you didn't use the official installer, then it's up to your distribution package manager.

Otherwise, you have to tell how you did install Qt in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the default installation folder/file path for QT Maintenance tool for Ubuntu Linux distro?

As of Ubuntu 19.10, it is simply not contained in the Ubuntu repositories. You have basically two options:

1. Download the [Qt Online Installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer) from the Qt website and use that to install a version of Qt for Android. The Qt Maintenance Tool will then be available at `/opt/Qt/MaintenanceTool`.

   You can delete the version of Qt Creator installed by this process if you prefer to keep the version from the Ubuntu repositories: `sudo rm -R /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/`
2. Or you could use [`aqtinstall`](https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall/), an unofficial Qt installer that can be used to install any Qt on any target platform. It's equivalent in function to the Qt Maintenance Tool while being equivalent in terms of interface to `apt` (means, it's a commandline tool rather than a GUI tool, allowing scripting with it).